# What ways can I convert a decimal to a human friendly time (hour:minute) and back?

Tags: cocoa-touch, math, type-conversion, date-conversion

I'm building a sliding visual control that returns a percentage offset (0.0 to 1.0), and I'd like to convert the decimal offset to a human readable time (like "9:45AM").

The times I will be displaying are from 4AM-Noon, in intervals of 15 minutes, but I'm more interested in general solutions because my exact requirements may change.

Current ideas include iteratively generating an array of string times given the start time (400), an interval (15), and end time (1200).
Or maybe doing integer division for the hours (8 in this example) `((offset*100)/(100/8))` and some modulo something for the minutes `((offset*100)%(60/15)*15)`. Not sure. Looking for something straightforward and robust that will allow for simple conversion between string, decimal, and date types.

Implementing by way of Swift in Cocoa Touch but solutions in any context will help.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula to translate the slider value [0.0, 1.0] to a time interval, or are you looking for a way to convert the translated value to a readable time format, or both?

Answer (score 0):

Never try to implement stuff like this by yourself. It costs you a lot of time and it's very hard to get a working solution for every language/region.
Besides that, the likelihood that someone else, in this case Apple, implemented this for you already is **too damn high**.

Check out the documentation of [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/). It generates a localized `NSString` from an `NSDate` for you.